# Is it possible to use more than one "template" element in one component in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

This question triggered in my mind while reading through Vue's official guide [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt).

I don't know if I find the answer to this question on proceeding further to read more from the official guide, but curious to know if it's possible or not.

Well, I'll update here as soon as I got to know the answer.

[Screenshot from official guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7P7r.png)

Comment: As long as it's inside the component's template, yes. like <template><template></template><template></template></template>

Comment: Well that works, but I'm particularly interested in more than one `<template>` elements as siblings. What I found is you can have multiple `<template>` elements as siblings specially in case of [SFC's](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) but the last one among them is considered to be rendered. Well if we put a conditional directive like `v-if` on them, then a single component can render different templates conditionally as shown [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key).

Answer (score 2):

A component must use a single template or component option object, and that template must provide a single root element to mount.  The template is converted into a render function internally, and Vue can only have 1 render function.

Your component can in turn contain a component that is dynamic, however.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: Well if we put a conditional directive like v-if on them, then a single component can render different templates conditionally as shown [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key).

Comment: Those ‘templates’ still must be contained in a single element in a single template.  There is also the `component` tag.  However, OP asked about multiple templates in one component,